# Item in list found but when I ask for location by index it says that the item can't be found

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, automation, python-requests

I am writing some code to get a list of certain counties in Florida for a database. These counties are listed on a website but are each on individual webpages. To make the collection process less tedious I am writing a webscraper. I have gotten the links to all of the websites with the counties. I have written code that will then inspect the website, find the line that says "COUNTY:" and then I want to get the location so I can actually get the county on the next line. The only problem is when I ask for the location it says it can't be found. I know it is in there because when I ask my code to find it and then return the line (Not the placement) it doesn't return empty. I will give some of the code for reference and an image of the problem.

Broken code:

```
links = ['https://www.ghosttowns.com/states/fl/acron.html', 'https://www.ghosttowns.com/states/fl/acton.html']
import requests
r = requests.get(links[1])
r = str(r.text)
r = r.split("\n")
county_before_location = [x for x in r if 'COUNTY' in x]
print(county_before_location)
print(r.index(county_before_location))
```

Returns:

```
['    </font><b><font color="#80ff80">COUNTY:</font><font color="#ffffff">'] is not in list
```

Code that shows the item:

```
links = ['https://www.ghosttowns.com/states/fl/acron.html', 'https://www.ghosttowns.com/states/fl/acton.html']
import requests
r = requests.get(links[1])
r = str(r.text)
r = r.split("\n")
county_before_location = [x for x in r if 'COUNTY' in x]
print(county_before_location)
```

Returns:

```
['    </font><b><font color="#80ff80">COUNTY:</font><font color="#ffffff">']
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDfQ.png)

Comment: You're searching for a list in a list, not a string in a list.

Comment: Where the code says `county_before_location = [x for x in r if 'COUNTY' in x]`, what do you expect to be the *type* of `county_before_location`? Does it make sense to look for something of that type, within a string? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`county_before_location` is a list and you are asking for the index of said list, which is not in r. Instead you would need to ask for `r.index(county_before_location[0])`.

Comment: You can also add [0] after your loop if it is always the first element that contains county you want. That way county_before_location is just the string and not a list with one element.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `county_before_location = [x for x in r if 'COUNTY' in x][0]`       
`print(r.index(county_before_location))`